# How to separate between returned XML values in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have this query that allows me to pull XML tags values from all its occurrence.
I want to leave it in one row but to separate between the values with delimiter such as '||'.

```
SELECT
    DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (
        XMLCAST (XMLQUERY ('levlel1/level2/level3/level4' PASSING XMLTYPE (xml_col) RETURNING CONTENT) AS CLOB),
        1000,
        1
    ) RULES
FROM
    table
```

The result is: Rule1Rule2Rule3

I want to have this result:
Rule1 || Rule2 || Rule3

Thank you.

Comment: You are not using PL/SQL. Your query is SQL (in Oracle's SQL dialect) rather than using Oracle's procedural language (PL/SQL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `XMLTABLE` to generate the values as rows and then aggregate using `||` as the concatenation delimiter:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(rule, ' || ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS rules
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
         'levlel1/level2/level3/level4'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(t.xml_col)
         COLUMNS
           rule VARCHAR2(50) PATH '.'
       );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name(xml_col) AS
  SELECT '<levlel1>
  <level2>
    <level3><level4>Rule1</level4></level3>
    <level3>
      <level4>Rule2</level4>
      <level4>Rule3</level4>
    </level3>
  </level2>
</levlel1>' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| RULES |
| --- |
| Rule1 || Rule2 || Rule3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jcUAiiO5)

Comment: When adding WHERE to get result for specific entity it shows result successfully. But without the WHERE I'm getting error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1..

Comment: So I added WHERE xml_col is not null and then I see error as "result of string concatenation is too long" So I think some of the records are just have too many results to concatenate..

Comment: @user1508682 You may need to add a `GROUP BY` clause to group by the primary key in your table.

Answer (score 3):

You may use FLWOR XQuery instead of just XPath and return concatenation of double pipe and node text inside a query:

```sql
with sample(col) as (
  select q'$
<level1>
  <level2>
    <level3>
      <level4>Rule1</level4>
      <level4>Rule2</level4>
    </level3>
    <level3><something>not relevant</something></level3>
  </level2>
  <level2>
      <level3><level4>Rule3</level4></level3>
  </level2>
</level1>$'
  from dual
)
select
  substr(xmlcast(xmlquery(
    'for $x in /level1/level2/level3/level4
    return concat("|| ", $x/text())'
    passing xmltype(col)
    returning content
  ) as clob), 4) as res
from sample
```

| RES |
| --- |
| Rule1 || Rule2 || Rule3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KG0xnOkk)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another easy way to do it via `string-join()` function.

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XFpt0MV1)

**SQL**

```
with sample(col) as (
  select q'$
<level1>
  <level2>
    <level3>
      <level4>Rule1</level4>
      <level4>Rule2</level4>
    </level3>
    <level3><something>not relevant</something></level3>
  </level2>
  <level2>
      <level3><level4>Rule3</level4></level3>
  </level2>
</level1>$'
  from dual
)
select
  xmlcast(xmlquery('string-join((/level1/level2/level3/level4/text()), " || ")'
    passing xmltype(col)
    returning content
  ) as clob) as res
from sample
```

**Output**

```
RES
Rule1 || Rule2 || Rule3
```